# How do I change my display brightness?

Tags: display, brightness

I'm using elementary OS Freya installed as a dual boot. Since installing everything was okay. Suddenly, the screen is very dark. With my F-keys I can not control the brightness. If I use my big screen (HDMI) all is okay. I've a Packard Bell EasyNote LS Laptop.

Intel Core i7-2670QM |
AMD Radeon HD 7670M, 1 GB VRam

Comment: Perhaps take a look here? http://askubuntu.com/questions/149054/how-to-change-lcd-brightness-from-command-line-or-via-script

Comment: Just an idea, but laptop might be having problems with battery and decreasing screen's brigthness is system's energy-saving plan? Otherwise I see no logical explanation in system dropping brightness to the ground.

Comment: It will most likely be helpful if you can disclose your graphics card.

Comment: Does anybody know if you can make keyboard shortcuts for brightness adjustments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've fix the problem: I had to change my brightness in Windows. Now all is normal. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 6):

Proper way to do it should be via `System Settings` -> `Power` -> `Display brightness`

[image]

Comment: Doesen't work for me... Nothing happens.

Comment: Lars, in that case it looks like a problem with acpi or video drivers.

Comment: What should I do now? Update my driver?

Comment: give it a try. download latest version from amd website, reboot, try to change brightness again

Comment: I updated my driver. Nothing has changed.

Comment: @LarsDit. could you please paste us with result of the following commands:
[ # grep . /sys/class/backlight/*/brightness ]
and [ # grep . cat /proc/acpi/video/*/*/brightness]
and [ # lspci -vvv ] - this command will produce lots of output. save it to pastebin service or something like that

Comment: http://hastebin.com/fonadevolu.xml

Answer (score 1):

**Use a bash script!**

My script based on kagronick's one is super easy to use, just set a number from 0 to 100:

**Usage:**

```
chmod +x light
./light 50
```

*This sets brightness to 50%*

Find it here:
https://github.com/appvoid/elementary-os-for-newbies/blob/main/light

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem where my function keys suddenly stopped working with brightness levels.  For me the fix was simple:

`echo manual | sudo tee /etc/init/brightness.override`

Restart machine

Answer (score 0):

Try xbacklight.

Its simple to control the screen brightness according to your needs through TUI.

Syntax is simple:

xbacklight n

where n is the percentage with which you want to increase or decrease the screen brightness.

Thus,

xbacklight -3

decreases the screen brightness by 3%

and similarly,

xbacklight +3   # Do not omit the + sign…

increases the screen brightness by 3%

Another way could be:

echo 600 > /sys/class/backlight/*backlight/backlight

You can change 600 with the brightness level you want. Higher number means more brightness.

Run this as a super user or alternatively, do

chmod 665 /sys/class/backlight/*_backlight/backlight

first and then run the above command.

Hope you found it useful.

Answer (score -1):

I just tested this. It works.

`cd /sys/class/backlight/*/`

`sudo chmod 777 ./brightness`

`sudo echo $(cat max_brightness) > ./brightness`

Comment: Could you explain what those commands do?

Comment: Change directory into the backlight folder. Change the file permissions for the `brightness` file to full read/write/execute for all users and groups, and then 'copy' the maximum brightness into the current brightness file. I could explain it in more technical detail if you want, but this is the gist of it.

Comment: I have two folders in `/sys/class/backlight/`, this only affects the first one.

Comment: Well one of them muse be for you screen. Does it work on either of them?

Comment: Nope, although I know this is related to my graphics card, not the permissions.

Comment: But the instructions here work http://askubuntu.com/questions/288265/display-brightness-problem-with-ubuntu-13-04