# how do i change my screen brightness?

Tags: release-freya, settings, display, kernel, brightness

My os had some wifi driver problem so i upgraded to linux kenel 4.2.8 .now my brightness setting is not working.I checked [How do I change my display brightness?](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/478/how-do-i-change-my-display-brightness) but no luck my icon is missing. [image: screenshot]

Comment: Why did you upgrade?

Comment: my wifi was not working.

Comment: Does it work now. Also what model is your laptop. I had no problems on 4.1 with Intel HD 3000 so can you try that version

Comment: any solve? It happens to me the same in my system, and i cant set my screen brigthteness and the button behavior. Thanks!

Comment: Nope I have new hardware parts which are only supported after kernel `4.3` and ubuntu comes with latest kernel, so I switched to ubuntu, except the brightness elementary have other problems like screen flickering in some kernel versions. I will be waiting for new elementary os Loki which is based on ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 1):

There are two solutions that come to my mind:

First one is to use the old kernel. On boot you need to open Grub >> Advanced options. There you can find the older versions.

Second solution is using "xbacklight". It's a command line tool to change the display brightness. For installation:

```
sudo apt-get install xbacklight
```

An example to change the brightness to 15 percent:

```
xbacklight -set 15
```

That are only workarounds and don't solve the the problem completely.